# Zooming multiple subviews in an UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, zooming, subview

How would I go about zooming multiple subviews of an UIScrollView simultaneously? I have a UIScrollView inside another UIScrollView (with paging enabled) and inside the inner scrollview I have four UIImageViews. I would like for the zoom to persist when I scroll to the next page, thus displaying the next image.

Relevant code follows:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.page2;
}
+(void)updateScale:(CGFloat)newScale{
    currentScale = newScale;
}
+(CGFloat)getScale{
    return currentScale;
}
```

from the outer, paging enabled, scroll view and

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale{
    [PhotoViewController updateScale:scale];
    NSLog(@"New scale set to %01f", scale);
    NSLog(@"This should be equal to %01f", [PhotoViewController getScale]);
}
```

from the inner scrollview.

currentScale is updated correctly according to the log output, but when I call `[page setZoomScale:[PhotoViewController getScale]];` for the updated `page` variable, nothing happens. `page` is allocated and initialized correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put all of your image views into an empty UIView, and add that view to your scroll view.